# How to purge dbus configuration?

Tags: debian, d-bus

I get some various errors at boot from dbus in my logs:

```
Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call" ...
```

I've been running this Debian sid system (systemd init) for years, so I suspect a bad mix of configuration.

Usually this type of problems can be fixed with

```
apt-get purge package
apt-get install package
```

But dbus being a low-level dependency it would remove pretty much all my packages.

`/etc/dbus-1/system.d` has quite some files in it, I'm not sure if erasing them is a good idea.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Have you checked the debian bug database to see if these rejected send messages are known bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could remove the configuration manually. Which files? You can check it by the following command:

```
# dpkg -L package
```

It lists all installed files by this package. Then you have to reinstall the package and create new config files. To do so just use this:

```
# aptitude -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confmiss reinstall package
```

You can also set this as a default behavior in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` -- just copy the following line to the file:

```
force-confmiss
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and these commands I didn't know. It didn't solve the whole problem though because many other apps adds configuration to dbus. Solved it with a fresh install. Marked as accepted because I'm not sure we can do any better otherwise.

Comment: If I were you, I would have tried to check all the files with `apt-file search`. I think a simple script which can sort and remove duplicates would provide a list of packages that have files in that location. Then reinstall them with `force-confmiss` parameter.